# How to establish network connection between Mac and Pi using serial cable?

Tags: serial, macos

I have managed to establish a connection from my Mac (OS X 10.9) to Raspberry  Pi (Raspbian 3.6.11) using a serial USB to TTL cable by following [these instructions](http://learn.adafruit.com/adafruits-raspberry-pi-lesson-5-using-a-console-cable).

I can successfully establish a serial connection to the Pi using `screen`, and operate the Pi normally.

I would now like to transfer files from my Mac to the Pi over this cable using PPP. I have tried following the instructions on [this page](http://elinux.org/RPi_Serial_Connection), specifically:

On the Pi:

```
sudo pppd noauth
```

I had to specify `noauth` to avoid the error:

```
pppd: The remote system is required to authenticate itself
pppd: but I couldn't find any suitable secret (password) for it to use to do so.
```

Then in the Mac Terminal:

```
sudo pppd -detach noauth proxyarp /dev/tty.usbserial-FTGCC2MV 115200 10.0.0.1:10.0.0.2 passive local maxfail 0 nocrtscts xonxoff
```

This gives me the error:

```
Wed Oct 30 13:26:56 2013 : publish_entry SCDSet() failed: Success!
Wed Oct 30 13:26:56 2013 : publish_entry SCDSet() failed: Success!
Wed Oct 30 13:26:56 2013 : Using interface ppp0
Wed Oct 30 13:26:56 2013 : Connect: ppp0 <--> /dev/tty.PL2303-000012FD
Wed Oct 30 13:27:26 2013 : LCP: timeout sending Config-Requests
```

If I enable `debug` on the client side I get:

```
Wed Oct 30 13:26:31 2013 : sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0xa0000> <magic 0x79e49366> <pcomp> <accomp>]
```

So it seems like an `LCP ConfReq` is being sent to the Pi but no response is received.

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: what stops you from getting a network cable instead?

Comment: @lenik nothing stops me getting a network cable, but if I use a network cable, I need two cables: one to power the device and one to communicate with it. If can do everything over a USB to TTL cable, I only need one cable. Simple as that.

Comment: If you only want to use one cable, why not use a WiFi dongle? Pretty sure this will also speed up your data transfers.

Comment: @myhd as it happens, that's exactly what I'm now doing :)

Comment: Still an interesting question in need of a solution...